# ¿Por qué no se le aplica a mi iframe la propiedad margin-left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, formularios, modal

Holaa, estoy haciendo un modal y para ello he creado un div y un iframe que será el que se mostrará en el modal; el problema es que al querer centrar el div con el iframe poniendo la propiedad `margin-left:` en el iframe, no hace nada; sin embargo con las propiedades `margin-top` y `margin-bottom` sí responde. ¿Qué podría ser? Dejo aquí los codes:

HTML:

```
    <div class="preft">
<iframe class="dost" src="./assets/steps/1/assets/iframe/index.php" height="400" width="400">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.dost').addClass('mover');
```

CSS:

```
.mover{
width: 70%;
height: 550px;
margin-left: -940px;  /* Exageración de margin-left para demostrar que no funciona  */
display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: ¿Que version de jQuery estas usando?

Comment: El iframe muchas veces tiene display: inline por defecto en la hoja de estilos del navegador, por eso pueda ser de que el margin-left este siendo aplicado incorrectamente. prueba agregando display: inline-block a la hoja de estilos del navegador

Comment: @EdgarGc la versión 3.6

Comment: @Unknow le he aplicado a `mover` unas nuevas propiedades, más lo que me has dicho, pero aún así no funciona. Actualizo el código

Comment: Estas líneas funcionan, compruébalas a ver si te dan una idea de cuál es el problema. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<
<body>

<div class="preft">
 <iframe style="margin-left: 200px;" src="https://www.w3schools.com" height=550px width=70%><\iframe>
</div>


</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

En el html te falta cerrar el iframe, probablemente por eso no te esté aplicando el estilo correctamente.